# Left axis values overlapping in linechart of MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

How to show graph on full screen. Left axis values overlapping so graph also getting disturbed. Check xml and java code of graph.

Please check Below image for clarification.

[image]

My xml--
    <

```
com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart 
     android:id="@+id/LineChart_netSale" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Java code:

```
LineDataSet setNetSale = new LineDataSet(yValsNetSale, "DataSet 1");
    setNetSale.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    setNetSale.setFillAlpha(110);
    setNetSale.setFillColor(Color.rgb(93, 188, 210));
    setNetSale.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    setNetSale.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(93, 188, 210));
    setNetSale.setLineWidth(3f);
    setNetSale.setDrawCircleHole(false);
    setNetSale.setValueTextSize(9f);
    setNetSale.setDrawCircles(false);

    List<ILineDataSet> dataSetsNetSale = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSetsNetSale.add(setNetSale); // add the datasets

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData dataNetSale = new LineData(xValsNetSale, dataSetsNetSale);

    // set data
    LineChart_netSale.setData(dataNetSale);
    LineChart_netSale.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    LineChart_netSale.notifyDataSetChanged();
    LineChart_netSale.invalidate();

    Legend legend_netSale = LineChart_netSale.getLegend();
    legend_netSale.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);

    LineChart_netSale.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    LineChart_netSale.setDescription("");    // Hide the description
    LineChart_netSale.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    LineChart_netSale.getLineData().setDrawValues(false);
    LineChart_netSale.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    LineChart_netSale.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    LineChart_netSale.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    LineChart_netSale.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    LineChart_netSale.moveViewToX(10);
    LineChart_netSale.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
    LineChart_netSale.setNoDataText("No chart data available");

    YAxis yrlineNetSale = LineChart_netSale.getAxisRight();
    yrlineNetSale.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    yrlineNetSale.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Comment: share your chart xml.

Comment: <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/LineChart_netSale"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: share you java code.

Comment: edit your question and post the codes of your java and xml. don;t post the codes in comment section. TIA

Comment: meanwhile u can check examples of MPChart here https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample

Comment: I think problem with **yValsNetSale** share code which inserting values in it....

Comment: Its simple float array

Comment: try to set maxValue on yAxis `LineChart_netSale.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(float max)`
other ideas could be your animation which is on an area of 2000x2000 or reduce the ammount of labels on your yAxis so they don't overlap

Comment: From what I can deduct from the existing information, I think the Y axis Maximum has a high value set, if that's true, you are using a yAxisValueFormatter and only formatting the first 5 values or so and setting it to 100,000 to 500,000. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the YAxisValue formatter . If you are not using a YAxisValueformatter I would be really surprised.